# Matching values in an Array with columns in a worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I have a worksheet of athletes whose names appear all in one row. I want to grab all of the data underneath these names (aka the whole columns) so that I can manipulate the data. My issue is that I'm not familiar with available methods or functions in Excel VBA so I have only gone as far as this:

```
Dim MyArray(0 to 9) as String

MyArray(0) = "Molly"
MyArray(1) = "Jane"
MyArray(2) = "Louis"
MyArray(3) = "Omar"
MyArray(4) = "Wendy"
MyArray(5) = "Greg"
MyArray(6) = "Tina"
MyArray(7) = "Andrew"
MyArray(8) = "Jen"
MyArray(9) = "Lucy"
```

I'm thinking of creating a script that will look through all the names and select the columns whose names match the values in the Array.

EDIT: I've uploaded an example WS [here](https://www.sendspace.com/file/3r5iug) for reference (please forgive me if this is not according to SO standards, still trying to figure out how this site works and I don't have enough rep to post images :D). I'm interested in manipulating the numbers in the "Total" row, and need to showcase it (along with the specific names that it belongs to). I want to iterate this manipulation over all instances that these names pop up in the WS though, so a loop of sorts would be necessary

Thanks again for the tips/help!

Comment: welcome to SO! :) Please, take [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to earn your first shiny badge ;)

Comment: Can you tell more with some sample data, so we can think more or upload capture image to some free site and post the link in your question.

Comment: Hey @Nicolas! Thanks for your response. I edited my post to give a bit more info as what I'm trying to learn.

Comment: I am not clear for the output. Tell me more. I think that you want to find names from array in the sheet. When found what you want to do? I means the sample output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop accross the columns. The code below assumes the columns & your array are in the same order and that you are interested in the first 10 rows of each column of sheet 1.

```
With Worksheets (1)
For x = 1 to (UBound (MyArray) +1)
    ' Select column
    Range (.Cells (1, x), .Cells (10, x)).Select
    ' Do whatever you want with the data
    '
Next x
End With
```

You can make this more intelligent using If statements to check whether the first cell in each column matches a name etc. but at least it's a start!

Comment: Yeah a For loop seems like a good idea here! I'm going to look up the methods you used and see what I can do. Thanks for the start.

Comment: No problem, @Jed everything in excel seems to involve a loop or two somewhere. www.tutorialspoint.com/vba and mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions are pretty useful.